# What does the + mean

Tags: happy-wars

I have some items with item mods that are basically just [skill name]+ but no idea what that means.

Example, I have 1 helmet with **Roar+** and another with **Stone Throw+**.  I'd imagine the + means the skill is boosted but I'd like to know exactly what it is boosting.  At first I would assume something like damage, but Roar skill does not seem to deal damage so I'm unsure why this item mod is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have an equipment with + it means you always start the match with that skill, and it is slightly stronger than if you got it during the match. The best way to see the effectiveness change is use a mage. The damage output increases substantially.

In the case of Roar+ the fear effect is slightly longer by half of a second

Answer (score 0):

It is just a simple way of saying +1 Roar, may be a bit unclear because it doesnt use a normal metric but it is the same. Also roar + would most likely mean it is a boost to your roars effectiveness.

Comment: Effectiveness meaning what?